# Fourier Analysis / Real Analysis

Tags: calculus, fourier-analysis

I have run into the following exercice from Grafakos' Classical and Modern Fourier Analysis: if $f$ is a function in $L_{1}(R)$, then one has to prove that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x)dx$ = $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x-\frac{1}{x})dx$. For those who have the book, it's p.107, exercice 2.2.10. I have tried considering its Fourier inverses, without much success. Thank you for your help!

Comment: your question is unclear? post the question as it in the book

Comment: it's exactly the question in the book. No more details

Answer (score 3):

Use the substitution $x=t-\frac{1}{t}$ we have
$$\begin{aligned}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)dx&=\int_{-\infty}^0f(t-1/t)(1+1/t^2)dt\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^0f(t-1/t)dt+\int_{-\infty}^0f(t-1/t)(1/t^2)dt\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^0f(t-1/t)dt+\int_{-\infty}^0f(t-1/t)d(-1/t)\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^0f(t-1/t)dt+\int_0^\infty f(t-1/t)dt\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t-1/t)dt
\end{aligned}$$

Comment: the substitution is not one-to-one, you cannot assume that, in your consideration the 2nd integral is from $-\infty$ to$ \infty$ (plot $x=t-1/t$)

Comment: @mwomath It's one-to-one for $t\in(-\infty,0)$. So the bounds for the 2nd integral is $-\infty$ and 0.

Comment: Nice!, thank you very much

Comment: To make is valid you can divide the integral from $-\infty\to 0$ and $0\to \infty$, but then how to find a formula for the inverse of $x(t)=t-1/t$

Comment: @mwomath There's no need to divide the integral. Because $t-1/t$ is one-to-one on $(-\infty,0)$, and has image $(-\infty,\infty)$.

Comment: @mvenzin You're welcome!

Answer (score -1):

Use the substitution $x=t-\frac{1}{t}$ we have
$$\begin{aligned}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)dx&=\int_{-\infty}^0f(t-1/t)(1+1/t^2)dt\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^0f(t-1/t)dt+\int_{-\infty}^0f(t-1/t)(1/t^2)dt\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^0f(t-1/t)dt+\int_{-\infty}^0f(t-1/t)d(-1/t)\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^0f(t-1/t)dt+\int_0^\infty f(t-1/t)dt\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t-1/t)dt
\end{aligned}$$